# How to call Asp.Net core Wep API service from Asp.Net core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, jwt

I have a Web Api with JWT authentication and I use `HttpClint` from `System.Net.Http`:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52975");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "<here is real token>");
```

when I try to call it:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("<here is real uri>");
```

I'm getting `Unauthorized` response. The bearer is good because I also checked it using Postman and from Swagger interface and all work good.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Also I tried:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <real token here>");
```

When I check on server side there is not authorization headers received.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of postman? you can also try it on http repl

Comment: here is the postman screen but why? https://www.udrop.com/plugins/imageviewer/site/show_image.php?idt=d21210e1a83e86916f851e6ff02c2bb7&f=9825

Comment: when I call exactly same endpoint I'm getting 401 Unauthorized

Comment: postman screenshot was mainly to double-check the headers being passed in. in this case, also make sure the "real url" is your entire url starting from "/api"

Comment: yeah, real url is good, do you have another ideas?

Comment: if the url is not correct then it would return "Not Found"

Comment: can you take a screen shot of the postman HEADERS tab (request)?

Comment: here is a headers from POSTMAN: https://i.imgur.com/OCgWCas.png

Comment: when I debug from API, there is not headers in the request from HttpClient

Comment: Please share your code where you are checking the `Authorization` header

Comment: I'm just checking with a debug tool in a HttpContext.Request.Headers

Comment: I tried to add some other headers, for example I added 'Referer' and it is received successfully by WebApi, but there is no sense with Authorization header